# Turn SVG Into Sequence Of Points

Tags: svg, polygon, bezier

Given an SVG, is there a library which helps me to turn any path of the file into a sequence of points which lie on the path, with the length of path between two consecutive points being 1 (or some other constant)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need for a library. The [SVGGeometryElement](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/types.html#InterfaceSVGGeometryElement) API makes this possible within a few lines of code:

```js
function getPointsAlongPath (path, distance) {
  const length = path.getTotalLength();
  const points = [];

  for (let step = 0; step <= length; step = step + distance) {
    points.push(path.getPointAtLength(step));
  }
  
  return points;
}

const result = getPointsAlongPath(document.querySelector('circle'), 5);
console.log(result.map(p => [p.x, p.y]));
```

```html
<svg width="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="none" stroke="black" />
</svg>
```